# How to use informer instead of spatial transformer in image registration using PyTorch in Python?

Tags: python, image, pytorch, registration

I want to use informer instead of spatial transformer in image registration. so can someone guide me how to use it?

I want to do image registartion. My programe is in pytorch python. A spatial transformer is already use but I want to replace this by using informer. There are some ptoblems, that informer can not process 3D data. so how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.